# Can properties of the nodes be regarded as a special type of nodes in Neo4j?

Tags: python, neo4j

My question is motivated by the following problem. 
I have a set of web documents from which I extract keywords. I want to store these data in Neo4j for further analysis (more or less graph mining including subgraph isomorphism problem): each web document is a node; hyperlink from one web document to another is a corresponding directed relationship; keywords are properties of the nodes. In this setting, keyword property may be attributed to several nodes (I hope this is doable).

I need help with the following questions (which I find quite difficult to answer knowing only very basic things about Neo4j):

1) Is it possible to select all nodes attributed with a specific property "keyword1"?

2) How can I select common (overlapping) keyword properties for 2 nodes "doc1" and "doc2"? i.e., common keywords for 2 web documents

3) Is it better to create some kind of string key for keyword properties (rather then use default auto-incremented integer)?

Any hints/recommendations/links will be highly appreciated.
I am using Python binding for Neo4j on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

global lookups are handled with indexes. You should probably build an index that holds both keywords, backed by lucene, that you then can ask combined queries on the nodes.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-java-embedded-index.html

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-indexes.html